# Mockito matcher for List of array of primitives

Tags: java, mockito

I am unable to find a mockito matcher for `List<byte[]>` i.e. a matcher for any List containing any number of byte arrays.

Basically, I want this in verify() method to be used like this:

```
verify(libDao).getAllLibraries(/* Matcher representing any List<byte[]> */);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question: what exactly do you want to verify?

1. The method is called with "anything": then go for [anyList()](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.22/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#anyList()) for example
2. The method is called with something that is **not** null; then [notNull()](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.22/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#notNull()) is for you
3. A very specific list

That last case goes like:

```
verify(libDao.getAllLibraries(Arrays.asList( expected values ! ) );
```

Alternatively, you could also use an ArgumentCaptor and "fetch" the passed object; to have a closer look on it "later on".

Edit: and of course; when you are not on Java 1.8; you can step back and use `anyListOf(Byte.class)` for example.

Or, for byte[]; this could do:

```
anyListOf(byte[].class);
```

Another disclaimer: make sure you are using a recent version of Mockito 2 in the first place. Don't go for PowerMock(ito) and let that restrict your ability to go for a recent version of Mockito.

Comment: Also if you are still on Java 7, you can use anyListOf(Byte.class)

Comment: So, I want a matcher which matches any list containing any byte arrays. If I use Arrays.asList( Byte.class) , it is showing error. I am on Java 8.

Comment: Sorry I missed that. I think my comment then needs to be anyListOf(Byte[].class).

Comment: Sorry my bad. Please see updated question. It is byte[] not Byte[]. anyListOf(byte[].class) works. But you guys were talking of Java 7. I am On java 8. It still works. Any comments ? Is there another better matcher for Java 8 in mockito ?

Comment: See my latest edit to my answer. I added an example for byte[]. And we should start the comments we need no more. But as said: if you still have problems, then please put up a [mcve] - code with error messages that is!

Comment: @GhostCat I have a sub queries. First is  Is there another better matcher for Java 8 in mockito ? I am asking this as I see you emphasized on Java 7 for anyListOf() ?

Comment: The difference here: Java 8 has improved **type inference** for generics. In other words: with java7 you have to srite anyListOf(Some.class) so the compiler **understands** the generic types required to make the whole thing *compile*. With java8, you can just put down anyList() - and the compiler will deduce everything from the method signatures. In other words: you can write more "generic" (haha, word pun!) code with Java8.

Comment: @GhostCat , but is not anyList() dangerous. See we are using it in Unit testing. Tomorrow, if some one passes List<float[]> also, it will accept that too. However, it should fail in such case. Hence, `anyListOf()` is only answer here not `anyList()`. What are your views on this ?

Comment: It depends on the **signature** of your method. And keep in mind: **generics** are merely a compile-time thing. They make it easier for you to write correct code. But at runtime, all the code is dealing with raw Objects instead. I guess you should do some reading around that topic.

Comment: Thats exactly what my point is. Tomorrow, if someone changes the return type of method for which test is written, anyList(), will still works. But anyListOf() will fail. Desired behaviour should be that the test should fail. The flexibility of generics will make test run successful even if return type is changed. Dont you think this is dangerious and hence anyListOf() is desired in unit test ?

Comment: We should stop this asking more questions in comments. But well: you have to understand the **limitations** of unit testing. A unit test only sees the "compile time" stuff of your code. So, if that code compiles fine with float[], why should the unit test fail now; given the fact that *anything* is an Object to Lists anyway?! But if float[] fails in production, because some persisted data contains byte[], not float[] ... then well, a unit test can't know that. So you rather need some kind of integration test for that.

Comment: Beyond that: feel free to write up a **new** question; were such a change to a method interface results in a "real" problem, that goes undetected by unit tests - including a real, working [mcve]. Then drop me a note, and I will look into it. Or we chart chatting; but of course, my consulting time is billed in upvotes ;-)